# How do we create OnException events on custom baseClass

Tags: c#

we have 2 custom class (baseClass and ChildClass) the child class has inherited from the baseClass
when we get a exception on childClass, OnException event on the baseClass should be called

it'll be like MVC Controller OnException Events

We will use for logging.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case it is not possible to do. The MVC OnException works because the framework catches any unhandled exceptions and forwards them to OnException. The framework code for calling a controller action is something like:

```
try
{
  controller.SomeAction();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  controller.OnException(ex);
}
```

The entire implementation depends on the *caller* of the code taking the responsibility to handle the exceptions. With a general calls that can be used by any code you can't make any assumptions on how the class will be called.

If we somehow can make all calls go *through* the base class we can make something similar:

```
public class Base
{
  public BlahaMethod()
  {
    try
    {
      DoBlaha();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      OnException(ex);
    }
  }

  protected abstract void DoBlaha();

  private void OnException(Exception ex)
  {
    // Handle exception
  }
}

public class Derived
{
  protected virtual void DoBlaha()
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exception with a [try-catch-finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0yd65esw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) construct. The only general exception handler (known to me) is the [unhandled exception handler in the appdomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your attention but how can I implement event handling  on inherited class ? I want to call the base class when an exception occured in child class 's methods. This methods does not have to overriden from base class, Methods can be belong to child class.

Comment: I strongly advise you to read the concepts I mentioned above. In the catch part of a `try-catch`-construct you can call a base class method, but I wouldn't do that. Try-catch-constructs are meant for to handle *exceptions*, which means that this is a exception of the normal workflow. Consider to organize your workflow without using exceptions as a "normal" alternative!